# SWT Cross-Platform Enter Detection

Tags: cross-platform, swt, key

I have a global filter (`Display.addFilter`) in SWT in which I want to detect <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. In Windows, pressing Enter generates `SWT.CR` in 'keyCode' part of KeyListener event. Is this assumption safe for all platforms, or should I check if

```
keyCode == SWT.CR || keyCode == SWT.LF?
```

Thanks.

Comment: If my answer was useful, please check it as your accepted answer.

Comment: No it wasn't the right answer, as I didn't want traverse event. It's a global key listener (filter) as specified clearly in the question.

Answer (score 32):

If you want to catch the event when the user presses the Enter key while a widget is in focus, use a `TraverseListener` or a Listener with type `SWT.Traverse`. Then, you check

```
if (event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN) {
    // The user pressed Enter 
}
```