# SWT Text Focus and default selection(return key) events

Tags: java, swt, ubuntu-11.10

I am having a strange problem on my RCP. I don't use Linux to develop so my knowledge for common bugs is very less. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 to try out the RCP.

In my RCP, I have an SWT Text that has two listeners attached to it - one for focus (`FocusAdapter`) and the other for `SWT.DefaultSelection`. In the `FocusAdapter`, I implement the `focusLost` method.

The behaviour is such, if and when the user edits the text and *hits the return key*, then the `SWT.DefaultSelection` listener's `handleEvent` will be called and display a message to confirm the new text and update the `Text` field. If the user edits the text but does *NOT hit the return key* and simply clicks outside the `Text` field, then the `focusLost` event is called which reverts the text back to the original text (`text.setText(originalText);`).

This seems to work fine when I launch it from Eclipse but when I export the product via Maven+Tycho, that behaviour seems to stop working. What happens is that when the user edits the text, it just reverts back to the original text irrespective of whether the user hits the return key or not, or simply clicks outside the `Text` field. No message dialog to confirm the edited text is displayed either.

From what I gather it seems to just use the focusLost event and the return key has no effect. I apologise if this is something obvious but I have not encountered this on a windows machine which is what I use for my primary development.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Listener` for `SWT.KeyUp` instead of the `SWT.DefaultSelection` and check if the pressed key was enter? That might be more reliable.

Comment: It doesn't work. Hence I came upon `SWT.DefaultSelection`. It works fine on the Windows machine and like I said on Ubuntu it works fine when launched from Eclipse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can listen for `SWT.Traverse` instead and check if `event.detail` equals `SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN`. I tested it on Linux and it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.addListener(SWT.Traverse, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            if(event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter pressed");
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

---

There is a related question here:

[SWT Cross-Platform Enter Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688266/swt-cross-platform-enter-detection)

Comment: Great advice! It worked! I wonder why though the other way didn't especially when it works when launching from Eclipse. Could it be a bug?

Comment: @nEm I'm not sure why your code didn't work after exporting. It might be worth posting it as a bug. I didn't test it myself in an RCP project, just simple SWT.

Comment: Yes I will setting it up as a product to export and see what happens. thanks once again.