# How to stop key event propagation on swt

Tags: java, swt

I have text widget and on KeyDown event of that text widget .

```
myText.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        if (e.keyCode == Keys.ENTER || e.keyCode == Keys.CARRIAGERETURN) {
            myButton.setFocus();
            e.doit = false;

        }
    }
});
```

i need to set Focus on a button widget that has a `KeyListener`.

the problem is when i press Enterkey on my text widget it also fire the `keyReleased` event for the button widget. how can i stop the `keyReleased` event for the button?

```
myButton.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
 if ( event.keyCode == Keys.ENTER ) {    
            //do Something
        }
    }
});
```

i have tried `event.doit = false` but it did not work.

Comment: Have a look at this: [SWT Cross-Platform Enter Detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688266/swt-cross-platform-enter-detection)

Comment: Try stopping the event on a traverse event, with a traverse listener. *Edit:* But of course, Baz always beats me to it at SWT questions. :)

Comment: @GGrec My apologies ;) Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: BTW: Where's that `Keys` class from?

Comment: you mean adding a traverse event for the button right? but as i have found the keyListener is called before the traverse event.

Comment: @Baz: That Keys class is a custom class created in my project.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you didn't use your own custom `Keys` class, unless your fields point to the SWT-specific key variables. (e.g. `Keys.ENTER = SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN`).

As you can see from the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) below, the `TraverseListener` gets notified first. You may cancel your events there.

```
/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class KeyTest
{

    // ==================== 3. Static Methods =============================

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new KeyTest();
    }


    // ==================== 4. Constructors ===============================

    private KeyTest()
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        createContents(shell);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if ( !display.readAndDispatch() )
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }


    // ==================== 5. Creators ===================================

    private static void createContents(final Composite parent)
    {
        final Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE);

        text.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener()
        {
            @Override public void keyTraversed(final TraverseEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Traversed!");
            }
        });

        text.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {
            @Override public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Key released.");
            }

            @Override public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println("Key pressed.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Same thing happens even if i remove the custom keys class. i have checked this by modifying your code. i have added a button and attachd  two listeners KeyListener and TraverseListener. and from keyPressed event of text widget i set Focus to button widget.  keyListener of the button is invoked before TraverseListener of the button.

Comment: @Sharif Is the `setFocus` triggering the `TraverseEvent` by any chance?