# How to start new line after press keyboard key is "ENTER" in SWT table cell?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, keyboard-events

**Condition:**
     I have problem regarding SWT table cell, 
     In this,  I am writing text in SWT table cell any text, then after I pressed keyboard ENTER key. When I pressed key then text start with new line same cell.

**Question:**
 What is code for this key Event (Keyboard "ENTER" key)with start new line in same cell?

Here, SWT table sample code:

```
public class KeyEnter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.FULL_SELECTION
            | SWT.HIDE_SELECTION);
    TableColumn column1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    TableColumn column2 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText(new String[] { "item " + i, "edit this value" });
    }
    column1.pack();
    column2.pack();

    final TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table);
    editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
    editor.grabHorizontal = true;
    editor.minimumWidth = 50;
    // editing the second column
    final int EDITABLECOLUMN = 1;

    table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // Clean up any previous editor control
            Control oldEditor = editor.getEditor();
            if (oldEditor != null)
                oldEditor.dispose();

            // Identify the selected row
            TableItem item = (TableItem) e.item;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            // The control that will be the editor must be a child of the
            // Table
            Text newEditor = new Text(table, SWT.NONE);
            newEditor.setText(item.getText(EDITABLECOLUMN));
            newEditor.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
                public void modifyText(ModifyEvent me) {
                    Text text = (Text) editor.getEditor();
                    editor.getItem().setText(EDITABLECOLUMN, text.getText());
                }
            });
            newEditor.selectAll();
            newEditor.setFocus();
            editor.setEditor(newEditor, item, EDITABLECOLUMN);
        }
    });
    shell.setSize(300, 300);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
   }
}
```

screen shot:[image]

This kind of output  want into SWt table.

Comment: All rows in a SWT Table have the same height. You can't have one row with two lines and the rest with one.

Comment: @greg-449: Is there any way, to start a text with new line?

Comment: [This](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/MultilineTablecell.htm) might be a starting point. In addition, use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688266/swt-cross-platform-enter-detection) to detect the enter key press event.

Comment: @Baz: What is code for for new Line?

Comment: @SIT Inserting a `\n` will do the job.

Comment: @Baz: Thank you so very much. its working.

Comment: @SIT please post your implementation as an answer so that other people get to benefit from it as well.

Comment: @Baz : OK I tried to put code over here , But characters limit is out. So what to do now ? How to put code?

Comment: @SIT Well, don't post your _whole_ code. Just post the bits that show how you did it.

Comment: @Baz : I got minor problem in this code, When I write all text then press "Enter" key all text comes in one line , But it should come in line by line in same table cell.  can you help me? what is my code mistake. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @SIT I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @Baz: In  Given Solution code. After writing any text  at particular cell then  press "Enter" key.** Problem**  Now effect of the Enter key all text character has come in one line,                                                             * I want after press "Enter" Key ***  it should come line by line (It manse one line completed then start with new line according to Cell Width).**  I think now you understand.

Comment: @SIT Did you try the code from my answer?

Comment: @Baz: Yes. I did it.

Comment: @SIT So, does it work for you?

Comment: @Baz: Its works for Multiline but when I  integrated , same thing happen as told you: mantion below.   ** Problem** Now effect of the Enter key all text character has come in one line, * I want after press "Enter" Key *** it should come line by line (It manse one line completed then start with new line according to Cell Width).**  should you required any screen shot (output of code current). can i upload screen shot?

Comment: @BAZ: is it possible to do stretchable manner to on swt table row? i need excel sheet table wrap text feature is it possible to do?

Comment: @SIT Stretchable manner? What does that mean? Maybe check out the [Nebula Grid](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php).

Comment: @Baz:  Hi, I upload a one screen shot so you can more helpful to me. I do not use  Nebula Grid before. same like pivot table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129803/discussion-between-baz-and-sit).

Comment: @Baz: I want to SWT table cell functionality like pivot table functionality like Wrap text and after editing the text field then cell width height increase decrease and all row data can arranged by a line by line according to cell width etc. please help me how to do this in only SWT table?

Comment: @SIT You can't. This isn't possible with the SWT Table. That's why I'm telling you to look at the Nebula Grid.

Comment: @Baz: Thank you So very much for supporting me.  I have increased my knowledge @ SWT table.We discuss a lot.

Comment: @Baz: could u help me, If I click backspace key on  table cell (where write a text) from given code then reduce size of table cell how to do?

Comment: @SIT I'm afraid I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I gave it a shot and it really is a fiddly thing this. I've managed to make it work in the following way: The table's `redraw()` method is called whenever the content of the editor changes (this is expensive if the table is large). This will guarantee that the table always shows the correct item (row) height. I've also added that the editor's `layout()` method is called for each change so that it'll be repositioned in case the row height changes and the item you're currently editing moves up or down in the table (caused by the change in item height).

This is by no means a good or nice solution, but it sort of does the job. Maybe you'll be able to fine tune it and make some improvements.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setText("Stackoverflow");

    final Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    int columnCount = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
    {
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.BORDER);
        column.setText("Column " + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.BORDER);
        item.setText(new String[]{"cell " + i + " 0", "cell " + i + " 1", "cell " + i + " 2"});
    }

    final Listener paintListener = event ->
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SWT.MeasureItem:
            {
                TableItem item = (TableItem) event.item;
                String text = item.getText(event.index);
                Point size = event.gc.textExtent(text);
                event.width = size.x;
                event.height = Math.max(event.height, size.y);
                break;
            }
            case SWT.PaintItem:
            {
                TableItem item = (TableItem) event.item;
                String text = item.getText(event.index);
                Point size = event.gc.textExtent(text);
                int offset2 = event.index == 0 ? Math.max(0, (event.height - size.y) / 2) : 0;
                event.gc.drawText(text, event.x, event.y + offset2, true);
                break;
            }
            case SWT.EraseItem:
            {
                event.detail &= ~SWT.FOREGROUND;
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    table.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, paintListener);
    table.addListener(SWT.PaintItem, paintListener);
    table.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, paintListener);

    final TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table);
    editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
    editor.grabHorizontal = true;
    editor.grabVertical = true;

    table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e)
        {
            Control oldEditor = editor.getEditor();
            if (oldEditor != null)
                oldEditor.dispose();

            TableItem item = (TableItem) e.item;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            Text newEditor = new Text(table, SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER);
            newEditor.setText(item.getText(1));
            newEditor.addModifyListener(me ->
            {
                Text text = (Text) editor.getEditor();
                editor.getItem().setText(1, text.getText());

                // Redraw the table so that it'll adjust the row height
                table.redraw();
                // Wait a bit and then relayout the editor, so it'll move to the correct position
                display.timerExec(100, editor::layout);
            });
            newEditor.selectAll();
            newEditor.setFocus();
            editor.setEditor(newEditor, item, 1);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        table.getColumn(i).pack();
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())

    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```