# How to get currently entered text in StyledText in Eclipse SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am currently working on a chat type window in eclipse rcp application.
I have created a StyledText where user will type some message and a system generated message will be visible to StyledText. I want to capture what user has typed in the current line. Especilly, I want to grab the test line entered by the user in StyledText not the whole text.
The example is given below.

System: Welcome

User: Hi

System: Log the ticket

User: where to log

In the above case, I want to track each sentence written by user like "Hi", "where to log" etc. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure StyledText is a good choice here. The user can move the cursor anywhere in a read/write StyledText and start typing. You can use `addModifyListener` to get told about changes to the text.

Comment: Greg Sir, what should be the best choice in this case instead of using styledText. By the way, is it possible to use InputStream in this case to grab the output ?

Comment: One choice is to use a read only StyledText for the output and a `Text` control for the user's input. You might want to use a TraverseListener to handle the user pressing Enter in the text field (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1692463/2670892))